# Copy specific data from one table to another in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update, nested, inner-join

I have two tables, one is `CurrentReport` and other is `Challan` table, and another is current report table that are showing in table. I copy the value of following column of currentReport table

```
 [Title],
    [ISBN],
    [Author1],
    [FinalStatus],
    [MssType]
```

but now I want to copy stepno of challan table having min date into work1 of currentreport table in both tables refrence no. are same. In challan table there is multiple enteries in challan table having same reference no among which I want to get stepno having min date.

Columns in `challan` tables are

```
       [ChallanNo]
      ,[ReferenceNo]
      ,[PersonID]
      ,[PersonCategory]
      ,[ChallanDate]
      ,[PreparedBy]
      ,[CreatedOn]
      ,[Publisher]
      ,[TemplateName]
      ,[TemplateSubject]
      ,[TemplateBody]
      ,[EmailAttachment]
      ,[PreviousProjectedDate]
      ,[PreviousReminderDate]
      ,[PreviousActionDate]
      ,[NextProjectedDate]
      ,[NextReminderDate]
      ,[NextActionDate]
      ,[ReminderText]
      ,[ReceivedDate]
      ,[StepNo]
      ,[ChallanStatus]
      ,[IsActive]
      ,[IsReceived]
```

Columns in `CurrentReport` table are:

```
 [ReferenceNo]
          ,[Title]
          ,[ISBN]
          ,[Author1]
          ,[FinalStatus]
          ,[MssType]
          ,[Work1]
          ,[GivenTo1]
          ,[ChallanDate1]
          ,[ReceivedDate1]
          ,[Work2]
          ,[GivenTo2]
          ,[ChallanDate2]
          ,[ReceivedDate2]
          ,[Work3]
          ,[GivenTo3]
          ,[ChallanDate3]
          ,[ReceivedDate3]
          ,[Work4]
          ,[GivenTo4]
          ,[ChallanDate4]
          ,[ReceivedDate4]
```

So please tell me how to update `currentreport` table as it has 200 entries and `challan` table has 700 enteries.

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: update CurrentReport
set Work1=ch.StepNo
from CurrentReport
inner join Challan ch on ch.ReferenceNo=CurrentReport.ReferenceNo

Comment: But this won't get you the minimum date step no. Break your problem into multiple parts - 1) Write a select to filter out the min date step no from Challan table. 2) Use this select to update entries. Try it on your own first and then ask for more help

Comment: but how please give any idea??

Comment: Whats the vendor you are using? I will post the answer for SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* check if this is working */
Step 1 - write select to filter out minDate -

```
SELECT c.ChallanNo, c.REFERENCENO , c.STEPNO FROM CHALLAN c
INNER JOIN CURRENTREPORT cr
on c.REFERENCENO = cr.REFERENCENO
WHERE RECEIVEDDATE IN (SELECT MIN(RECEIVEDDATE)
FROM CHALLAN cn
GROUP BY (STEPNO))
```

/* if the above is working */
STEP 2 - update based on the results above

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT c.ChallanNo, c.REFERENCENO , c.STEPNO FROM CHALLAN c
INNER JOIN CURRENTREPORT cr
on c.REFERENCENO = cr.REFERENCENO
WHERE RECEIVEDDATE IN (SELECT MIN(RECEIVEDDATE)
FROM CHALLAN cn
GROUP BY (STEPNO))
)

UPDATE CURRENTREPORT SET WORK1 = ch.STEPNO FROM CURRENTREPORT c INNER JOIN cte ch 
on c.referenceNo = ch.referenceNo
```

Comment: Let me know if you face issues!